# Firebase does not deploy updated version

Tags: firebase, actions-on-google

I am building an "actions on google" application with firebase hosting the node.js back-end.

First deployment was successful and provided a webhook which works fine. 
After updating my .js files I run:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

and get the following output:

```
=== Deploying to 'monprogrammetele-c5169'...

i  deploying functions

i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...

✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled

i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

✔  Deploy complete!
```

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/monprogrammetele-c5169/overview

Everything looks fine except that when I test with the simulator
https://console.actions.google.com/project/......
I still get the old version running....

The only difference I can see between the initial deploy and this one is that firebase is not providing a webhook link like it did the first time:

Function URL: https://us-central1-programmetele-82c89.cloudfunctions.net/teleProgram

I have assumed it is still the same.

Comment: After "preparing functions directory for uploading..." there should be another step, that step is where it actually deploys the new function code, it's weird that this step is missing here.

Answer (score 0):

The missing URL during deployment was fixed in version [3.16.0](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v3.16.0) of the CLI.  Please upgrade it like this:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but I should have mentioned that I already tried to run npm install -g firebase-tools,  didn't work.

Comment: Wondering if it could be linked with the firebase.json  file being empty (actually : {]). But I couldn't find any example on  the web of a node.js deployment where this file is not empty.

Comment: I run deploy in debug mode :firebase deploy --debug  --only functions  but couldn't see anything  wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was on my side, did some changes on index.js for local testing that were incompatible with firebase. I would suggest though that firebase is more explicit in its debugging messages.
Thanks for the help,

```
 Thierry
```